# Can't create a hash inside a method

Tags: ruby, hash

When I run this method that creates a hash of a letter counter, it runs fine

```
def letter_count(str)
  ashh = Hash.new

  str.each_char do |x|
     if x != " "
       ashh["#{x}"] = str.count(x)
     end
  end

  return ashh
end
```

However, when I create a method that uses a hash to convert a string into morse code it wouldn't let me create the hash inside the method i have to put it outside. Why am i able to do so for the first method but not the second?

```
def morse_encode(str)
arrWords = str.split

Morse = {
 "a" => ".-",
 "b" => "-...",
 "c" => "-.-.",
 "q" =>"--.-",
 "t" => "-",
 "i" => "..",
 "h" => "....",
 "n" => "-."
}
   output = []
word = ""
 arrWords.each do |x|

 word = []
 currentWord = x.split("")

 currentWord.each do |y|
   word.push(MorseHash[y].to_s)
   end

 output.push(word.join(" "))
 end

return output.join("  ")

end
```

The second code does not run unless i move the hash outside the function.

Comment: What does "wouldn't let me do it" mean? Do you get an error message? What does it say? How would you fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Morse` is treated as a class, try changing it to any other valid form of hash definition,

you can do

```
morse = Hash.new
morse = {}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Strictly speaking `Morse` is treated as a constant. Same difference it has to be outside of a callable method.